# Searchbar in react to call table of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create a searchbar in react that creates a table of data from an API inside the current view.

```
  async function handleSearch() {
    console.log("searching...", searchRef.current?.value);
    setMessage("Searching...");
    var headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "auth-token": token,
    };

    fetch(
      "http:"..
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers,
      }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      setMessage("");
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log("erROR", response);
        return null;
      } else {
        console.log("success", response);
        this.searched = true;
        let productList = response.json()
        return productList;
      }
    })
    .then((responseData) => {
      console.log("responseData", responseData);

      // setting resonseData to productList
       setProductList(responseData);
    });
  }
```

For some reason this is ridiculously hard to get working.

I would imagine the code above would work and fill the table with the correct array, but is it not.

The JSON response is like this and works properly in the console with the search component currently.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: could you please provide any stackblitz?

Comment: It seems you are not storing result(response from backend) in either component state or in props. From productList where is coming ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to add **productList** as state variable like below.

```
// We need to initialize with empty array. Otherwise while rendering component for the first time it will try to access map of undefined(productList).

const [productList,setProductList] = useState([]);

// And then in your fetch call you can store data inside productList

fetch(
  "http://localhost:5000/adverts/mwap?searchTerm=" +
    encodeURIComponent(searchRef.current.value),
  {
    method: "GET",
    headers: headers,
  }
)
  .then((response) => {
    setMessage("");
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      console.log("erROR", response);
      return null;
    } else {
      console.log("success", response);
      this.searched = true;
      let productList = response.json()
      return productList;
    }
  })
  .then((responseData) => {
    console.log("responseData", responseData);

    // setting resonseData to productList
     setProductList(responseData);
  });
```

Comment: this returns an error of  TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null now, need to check if there's data before?

Comment: could you console log productList after setting data in 2 nd callback of then??

Comment: I have edited my answer. The error is coming bcz for the first time when component rendered we are setting productList with null. So for the first time when component is rendered productList will null. If we intialize with empty array we dont get that error

Comment: For some reason now, the table generates, but there is no data inside the table

Comment: Did you intialize productList with empty array ?? Did you console log productList after setting data in 2 nd callback of then??